# Php file request through ajax using two variables from jquery

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, variables, request

I have this: A javascript file that does a request to a php file.

I have two variables called Lat and Lng in my javascript.
When I do the request to the php file with ajax I would like those two variables to be translated in to php values that the php file will use.

I hope this explains it clear enough.
How can I do this?

Code: Javascript

```
var lng = center.lng();
var lat = center.lat();
$.ajax({
    url: "ajax.php"
}).done(function(data){};
```

Code: Php

```
$lat = '';
$lng = '';
```

What I want is those two variable values from the Javascript in the php with each request.

If it helps to know what I'm doing exactly:
I'm getting the longtitude and latitude from the google maps center.
These values I want to use in the file_get_contents url in my php.
Every time the request happens the url gets dynamic because the values will be send with the request.

Comment: Can you please post the code that you are currently using? As it currently stands it's not too clear what the problem is.

Answer (score 1):

Script to request php file through POST data:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
var longitude = center.lng();
var latitude = center.lat();
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: "ajax.php",
    data:{longitude:longitude, latitude:latitude},
    success: function(){
        alert('Success');
    }
}).done(function(data){console.log(data);};
</script>
```

And in PHP file:
you can get values as:

```
$longitude = $_POST['longitude'];
$latitude = $_POST['latitude'];
```

Hope this helps!!!

Answer (score 0):

you need to send the variables through your ajax request first of all. I use something like this

```
{lng:lng,lat:lat},
```

and then you make a request in php something like this

```
if ($_REQUEST['lng']) {
    $lng = $_POST['lng'];
    $lat = $_POST['lat']
}
```